# How to find other relations of a node in a query in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph is like this:

```
a-[sends]->b-[sends]->d
c-[sends]->d
a-[hostedOn]->S1
a-[hostedOn]->S3
b-[hostedOn]->S1
b-[hostedOn]->S2
```

I have queries which filter on the property of "sends" relationship and returning the desired results. Now I also want that in the same query if I can also ask it to return "hostedOn" as well. Say, my output is b-[sends]->d, how can I also have in the same output b-[hostedOn]->S1 & S2? b & d will change every time depending on the filters applied on "sends" relation.

Comment: Perhaps share the query you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, given the very little information provided. Many solutions are possible, depending on exactly what you need to be returned and if you want any aggregation.

```
MATCH (a)-[r:sends]->(b)
WHERE r.foo = "bar"
MATCH (a)-[r1:hostedOn]->(s1), (b)-[r2:hostedOn]->(s2)
RETURN a, r, b, r1, s1, r2, s2;
```

This query assumes all `a` and `b` nodes must also have `:hostedOn` relationships, so there are no `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses.

Comment: Thanks much! This helped and also increased my understanding :)